# Access angular element from parent element

Tags: html, angular, typescript

Im implementing an editable-data-table in angular. When I click a cell and want the `app-editable-text` to "open".

When I click the cell I want to set the property of child element. When I click on a cell the `onCellClick` method triggers, and I want to access it's correspondig `app-editable-text` component and set its isOpen property to true.

```
<td (click)="onCellClick(editableValue)" mat-cell *matCellDef="let element; index as i">
  <div (click)="onCellClick(editableText)" class="editable-value-container">
    <app-editable-text id="0" *ngIf="tableInfo.columnTypes.get(column).name === 'Text'" #editableValue
      [ngClass]="{'edit-active': editableValue.isOpen}" [value]="element[column]">
    </app-editable-text>
  </div>
</td>
```

Inside the `onCellClick` the `editableText` is `undefined`

Working example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-l2ybfg
I need the implementation of the onCellClick. I can't figure out how to change the isOpen property of the editable-'text/number/...'.

Comment: With the information at hand, it's very difficult to understand the context. Plus there are also quite a lot of unknowns. Would you mind creating a minimal complete verifiable example replicating your issue? You can use [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/angular/qvndadbboey?file=app%2Ftable-basic-example.ts) in order to do that.

Comment: thank you! I will do that right now. Sorry I thought it's clear what I want to achieve.

Comment: I created a a stackblitz project to clarify the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make isOpen to an Input

```
export class EditableNumberComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() value;
  @Input() isOpen = false;

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }
}
```

And change the input value

```
<td #me (click)="me.isOpen = !me.isOpen" mat-cell *matCellDef="let element; index as i">
  <app-editable-text *ngIf="types.get(column) === 'Text'" [isOpen]="me.isOpen" [value]="element[column]"></app-editable-text>
  <app-editable-number *ngIf="types.get(column)==='Number'" [isOpen]="me.isOpen" [value]="element[column]"></app-editable-number>
</td>
```

Comment: Thank you! I didn't think there is a solution for this. This was a very pleasant surprise.

Comment: PS.: If you have more types you should consider using *ngSwitchCase instead.

Comment: I must be doing something wrong but this is what happens: when I open the first it opens, but after that changing me me.isOpen doest do anything. How am I supposed to close and reopen it?